# How to trigger an event after scrolling a certain amount (up or down) from your current position?

Tags: jquery

I have not yet found a solution to my specific problem. My main menu toggles open and closed on click. I want the menu to optionally close after a user has scrolled 100px up or down from the ***current*** position. I need to calculate + or - 100px from the **current** window position. Scenario: A user scrolls 1/3 of the way down the page and opens the menu, then decides not to click on anything, but continues to scroll up or down the page. The menu should automatically close after the user has scrolled 100px. Currently, the menu closes immediately on scroll, which can be easily done by mistake.

```
  $(window).on('scroll', function () {
  if ($('.nav--column').is(':visible') && **user has scrolled +- 100px**) {
    $('.nav--main-menu').find('a.level_one.current').removeClass('current');
    $('.nav--column').removeClass('expanded');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the users click to open the menu, you can store the current `scrollTop`:

```
var LAST_SCROLL = $(window).scrollTop();
```

In your code:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
   if ($('.nav--column').is(':visible') && Math.abs(LAST_SCROLL - $(window).scrollTop()) > 100) {
   $('.nav--main-menu').find('a.level_one.current').removeClass('current');
$('.nav--column').removeClass('expanded');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks...this works great when I'm at the top of the window!

I have a sticky header that hides and displays like on this site: https://osvaldas.info/examples/auto-hide-sticky-header/?reactive-plus. I need this to work no matter how far I've scrolled down or up the page.